# How do I prove that f is analytic? Complex functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration, analytic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

I would like to show that if $F$ is analytic in $A\subset \mathbb{C}$, then so is $f$ where $f =\dfrac{F(z)-F(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ for $z \in A, z \neq z_0$ and $f(z_0)=F'(z_0)$ for $z_0$ some fixed point in A.

I was trying to use Cauchy's integral formula. Maybe?
I don't know. I Need Help.

Comment: Morera's theorem perhaps.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. If I prove continuity it's done with Morera's! Thanks!

Comment: $F(z)-F(z_0)$ and $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ are both analytic in $A-\big\{z_0\big\}$ so their product is analytic; you only need to check that $f(z_0)$ is sensible (e.g. this is a removable singularity...)

Comment: If $F(z)$ is holomorphic at $z_0$ then $F(z)=F(z_0) +\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$ for $|z-z_0|< r:=\operatorname{dist}(z_0, \partial A).$ Then
$${F(z)-F(z_0)\over z-z_0}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}(z-z_0)^n$$